# How to set the severity level in allure report, using pytest-bdd

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, bdd, allure

I am using pytest-bdd with allure to generate the reports, In generated allure report i can see the severity level is NORMAL by default, how can i set the Severity level as i needed.Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of allure report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRgj9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add severity to your allure report by @severity decorator.

First, you need to import severity and severity level from allure and add it to pytest-bdd test steps.

For example:

```
from allure import severity, severity_level

@severity(severity_level.CRITICAL)
@scenario('test_user.feature', 'Check user list by page')
def test_check_user_list_by_page():
    """Check user list by page."""
```

Comment: Actually i tried this solution but it din't work as it throws the following..""from allure import severity, severity_level
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'severity_level""

Comment: You must be using new `allure-pytest-commons`, where it is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via **Overhave** usage: https://github.com/Tinkoff/overhave

For example:

```
@severity.critical
Feature: My feature

Scenario: My scenario
  When I am user
  ...
```

Full example from framework documentation is here: https://github.com/Tinkoff/overhave/blob/master/docs/includes/feature_example.rst

You will get necessary severity level in Allure report after test is finished.